# Input Overflow with PyAudio

Tags: python, pyaudio

I have searched and tried all the basic fixes for this but cannot get this basic recording script to work. I have tried changing the chunk size an sample rate with no luck.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pyaudio, wave, time, sys
from datetime import datetime

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

current_time = str(datetime.now())  #"Date/Time for File Name"
current_time = "_".join(current_time.split()).replace(":","-")
current_time = current_time[:-7]
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = 'Audio_'+current_time+'.wav'

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels = CHANNELS, rate = RATE, input = True, input_device_index = 0, frames_per_buffer = CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    print i
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)

print("* done recording")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

When running the code I get the following error:

```
./record 
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
* recording
0
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./record", line 25, in <module>
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 605, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames)
IOError: [Errno Input overflowed] -9981
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a case to pass the `IOError` and it worked!

```
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    print i
    try:
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    except IOError:
        pass
    frames.append(data)
```

Comment: Check out my comment and link on this SO question for further information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235666